# Fastest way to generate shuffled range array form zero to x

Tags: python, numpy, random, range

I'm trying to find the fastest way to generate a shuffled array of indices. A shuffled range from 0 to a number, so to say.

Currently I've compared these two methods:

```
setup = "import numpy as np; idxlen = 1000; rng = np.random.default_rng(); matrix = -np.ones([100,idxlen],dtype=int)"
test1 = "rand_idxs = np.arange(idxlen); 
         rng.shuffle(rand_idxs); 
         matrix[0][:] = rand_idxs"
test2 = "matrix[0][:] = rng.choice(range(idxlen),idxlen,replace=False)"
print(timeit.timeit(test1, setup, number = 10000))
print(timeit.timeit(test2, setup, number = 10000))
```

Returning the following timings:

```
0.1846354000736028
0.950088300043717
```

I assume that under the hood, the rng.shuffle() method randomizes the indices of the array past to it, and rearranges it according to those indices. Now, since I'm generating an array containing every integer from 0 to a certain number, this practically corresponds to generating randomized indices. So I can't shake the feeling that there is a faster way to do what I'm trying to achieve. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove range from the test two then you will see changes and find `test2` is faster then first

```py
import timeit
setup = "import numpy as np; idxlen = 1000; rng = np.random.default_rng(); matrix = -np.ones([100,idxlen],dtype=int)"
test1 = "rand_idxs = np.arange(idxlen); rng.shuffle(rand_idxs); matrix[0][:] = rand_idxs"
test2 = "matrix[0][:] = rng.choice(idxlen,idxlen,replace=False)"
print(timeit.timeit(test1, setup, number = 10000))
print(timeit.timeit(test2, setup, number = 10000))
```

Now for testing

**for idxlen=1000**

```py
0.15045420000024023
0.24143790000016452
```

**for idxlen=10000**

```py
1.4334205999984988
1.3395810999973037
```

**for idxlen=100000**

```py
14.489788099999714
8.599601199999597
```

Also there is one more method that is [`np.random.Generator.permutation`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permutation.html#numpy.random.Generator.permutation)

And the testing for this method are these

```py
test3 = "matrix[0][:] = rng.permutation(idxlen)"
```

**for idxlen=1000**

```
0.1567758999990474
```

**for idxlen=10000**

```
1.4174363000020094
```

**for idxlen=100000**

```
13.964398899999651
```

---

##### In the end the comparison of timing between all three

##### Graph for `number=10000`

[image]

[Code for graph](https://pastebin.com/L9J9svbg)